# on upload get all file names in array in php

Tags: php, mysql

What i want to know is how can I get a list [specifically array] of all the files name in a directory when I select it through upload button, after which I would upload that array of files to the database. As one file as a single entry. So how do I do that?
No to forget that I just need files names and I have to upload these names only not the actual files.

Comment: "all the files name in a directory when I select it through upload button" please clarify this.

Comment: yeah all names in a directory, names of all files in that. Thats what I want to access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are the files on the server? if you hopping to have a button you click on  browser and open a folder on the end user this will not work. most browsers only allow single file selection

Comment: yeah thats what m trying to do, so if not multiple file selection then how can I select files one by one and then get all those names to be uploaded to the database?

Comment: you would simply need to have multiple upload box's. or you can simply hard code 5 box's for example but if you unsure how many files will be, then you would need to use some js to keep adding more input box's as the user requires

Comment: here is a great example of a diffrent approach to getting multiple files going using 1 input box that keeps adding the items into a list to be posted http://the-stickman.com/web-development/javascript/upload-multiple-files-with-a-single-file-element/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ftp, this function will return all of the filenames of a directory in an array.

```
function ftp_searchdir($conn_id, $dir) {
    if(!@ftp_is_dir($conn_id, $dir)) {
        die('No such directory on the ftp-server');
    }
    if(strrchr($dir, '/') != '/') {
        $dir = $dir.'/';
    }

    $dirlist[0] = $dir;
    $list = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $dir);
    foreach($list as $path) {
        $path = './'.$path;
        if($path != $dir.'.' && $path != $dir.'..') {
            if(ftp_is_dir($conn_id, $path)) {
                $temp = ftp_searchdir($conn_id, ($path), 1);
                $dirlist = array_merge($dirlist, $temp);
            }
            else {
                $dirlist[] = $path;
            }
        }

    }

    ftp_chdir($conn_id, '/../');

    return $dirlist;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?
    if (isset($_POST[submit])) {
    $uploadArray= array();
    $uploadArray[] = $_POST['uploadedfile'];
    $uploadArray[] = $_POST['uploadedfile2'];
    $uploadArray[] = $_POST['uploadedfile3'];
    foreach($uploadArray as $file) {
    $target_path = "upload/";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['$file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['$file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['$file']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
    } else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
    }
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload-simple.php" method="POST">
    <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
    Choose a file to upload:
    <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
    </p>
    <p>Choose a file to upload:
    <input name="uploadedfile2" type="file" />
    </p>
    <p>Choose a file to upload:
    <input name="uploadedfile3" type="file" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
    </p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This Might be Solve your Problems

Answer (score 0):

If the files already exist on the server you can use `glob`

```
$files = glob('*.ext'); // or *.* for all files
foreach($files AS $file){
    // $file is the name of the file
}
```